# Getting a 404 Not Found error when trying to get data from localhost in angular

Tags: angular, http, localhost

I am trying to get data from my SpringBoot application (http://localhost:51535/company/BABA) and display it using Angular.

This is my proxy.conf.json file:

```
{  "/company/*": {    
    "target": "http://localhost:51535/company/BABA",    
    "secure": false,    
    "logLevel": "debug"
    }
}
```

And this is my service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http'
import {IData} from './data';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CompanyserviceService {

    private _url: string = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://localhost:51535/company/BABA";

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getData(): Observable<IData[]>{
    return this.http.get<IData[]>(this._url);
  }

}
```

I have tried to work around the CORS issue by using "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/" as a prefix in my URL, as suggested here on stack.

This is from the browser console from localhost:4200 -

[Error on browser console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0XDlj.png)

Please tell me how can I fix this.

Comment: "This is from the browser console" ? ?? I dont see any info for this line. Where is the image? There is chrome plugin to temporarily working around with COrs issue. Google it. That would help

Comment: I don't think that the cors-anywhere site would work for localhost request. If you own the API, which you seem to do, just add correct cors headers to that API

Comment: I worked out the issue, had to add the @CrossOrigin annotation in my Spring Boot Controller class, thanks though!